The first simplicial homology of $S^2.$
I am using the following $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^2:$



And I am getting the $\partial_1$ map to be the zero matrix while the $\partial_2$ matrix is the $$
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1\\
1&1\\
-1&-1\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
In the following sequence $$0 \to \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z^3 \to \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{0} 0 $$
I do not know how to reach the simplicial homology $H_1(S^2)$ is zero (as mentioned here Computing simplicial homology of the 2-sphere as I know that all homologies must be the same), it is always giving me $\mathbb Z^2$ Could someone clarify this to me please?

I think you need three vertices for a $\Delta$-complex structure on $S^2$. See this post and also problem 4, page 3 of these course notes.

What about the direction of my a's, is it ok to have it opposite direction to what is in the notes you shared?@pyridoxal_trigeminus

I guess the problem with me is in the image of $\partial_2,$ then how having 3 vertices will change the image of $\partial_2$ to become $\mathbb Z^3$?@pyridoxal_trigeminus

I think I am on the right track @pyridoxal_trigeminus

The issue is how you labelled your vertices, the ones connected by $c$ aren't actually identified as you have drawn. Below is how I would label the vertices,

I believe the only identification to make on the vertices is $v_2$ and $v_3$. Using the same edge and face labels as you have, you should now get:

$\partial_1 a = v_2 - v_1, \ \partial_1 b = v_4 - v_2$ and $\partial_1 c = v_4 - v_1 = \partial_1(a+b)$ $\implies$ Ker$\partial_1 = \langle a+b-c \rangle \ ( \cong \mathbb{Z})$

$\partial_2 U = a+b-c, \ \partial_2 L = a+b-c \implies$ Im$\partial_2 = \langle a+b-c \rangle \ (\cong \mathbb{Z})$

Hence, $H_1(\Delta) = \frac{Ker \partial_1}{Im \partial_2} = \frac{\langle a+b-c \rangle}{\langle a+b-c \rangle} \cong 0$


Edit: Made some corrections thanks to Ben and also added a tip/tool to be able to do this kind of exercise more reliably
One tip for doing these constructions is to use the Euler characteristic to double check. For instance, in your construction, you have 1 vertex, 3 edges and 2 faces. Giving you, $\chi (\Delta) = 1-3+2 = 0$. If you are familiar with the Euler characteristic, you will know that $\chi(S^2) = 2$ so something has gone wrong here. You can actually go further and identify that the errors are most likely in the vertex count but that's not the point. I'm not sure if this always works (probably does for "nice" spaces just not in general) but, even if not, it's a nice heuristic to use. That is, if you get different characteristics then you definitely made a mistake but equal characteristics doesn't necessarily mean your structure is correct.

I'd recommend against writing $\ker \partial_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}$, $\operatorname{im} \partial_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}$ followed by $\frac{\ker \partial_1}{\operatorname{im} \partial_2} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{Z}} = 0$ because someone will understand it as "If $\ker \partial_1$ and $\operatorname{im} \partial_2$ are both isomorphic to the same group, then $H_1$ is trivial" which is not true and a common pitfall with these computations.

@BenSteffan good point, I think I wrote it because of their remarks on getting $\mathbb{Z}^2$ but I honestly don't remember. I'll correct it, thanks
